# Issue while doing Unit Testing for Code Performance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I was testing my code to check how it will behave if we think that 100 users submitted their registration all at once !!!

My code is in PHP Laravel 5.2 and JQuery Ajax is below.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var 
     data={'Role' : "Role"+i},
     request = $.ajax({
        url:                'http://localhost:1234/Practise/public/api/SaveRoleApi',
        type:               "POST",
        data:               JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async:  true,
        success: function(d){ console.log(d); }
     });
}
```

Out of 100, I am not successful in submitting more then 88 records.

I am using MySQL Database.

**if my above code will add records sequentially...id there any way to test 1000 concurrent requests from one computer?**

Comment: This will test 100 sequential requests not 100 concurrent requests.

Comment: No. Please check `async: true,` in ajax

Comment: Use Apache Benchmark, JMeter, loader to do this. Writing ajax in a loop is the worst performance testing method. Also read about locking in MySql.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting multiple requests from one browser using JavaScript to create all the connections is not a good idea, you are indeed not testing concurrency very well.

Consider using an actual load testing tool like JMeter (I definitely recommend this), or at least parallel curl requests in a batch script.

```
for n in {1..1000}; do
    for i in `eval echo {$n..$((n+999))}`; do
            echo "club $i..."
            curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"param1":"xyz","param2":"xyz"}' -s "http://localhost:1234/Practise/public/api/SaveRoleApi" >> log.txt
    done &
    wait
done
```

Comment: But, where it is about async?

Comment: Again, I advice you to use an actual tool for it. But in the case of the command line script, the `&` at after the `done` what it does its to tell the shell to run that in a separate thread, so, all of those runs parallel.

Comment: Which tool? It's bad if I am doing testing for parallel request.

Comment: JMeter is great for that. No, it is not bad to do this like this, it's just that a tool could provide a lot more information and features.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use a tool specific for this purpose like [loader](https://loader.io/). Keep in mind that your web app should be accessible from the outer world.

Comment: I can't use this because my db table need unique records. This tool will not allow to do such kind of concurrent testing.

Comment: I am sure that you can use it the way you want. Have a look at payload files (http://support.loader.io/article/17-payload-files#variable-sets) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using PHP curl's multi functionality. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$ch = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $data = "Role=Role$i";
    $ch[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:1234/Practise/public/api/SaveRoleApi');
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Number of post fields, in this case just one.
    curl_steopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc = CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
while ($active and $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if(curl_multi_select($mh) !== -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: But, where it is about async request?

Comment: curl_multi is asynchronous, as the link states at the top of the page.